# How can I dynamically get the network's gateway ip in docke-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'am working on this simple docker-compose file.
It starts a node.js server that connects to a postgresql database **hosted by the host machine**.

```
version: '3'
services:
  node-server:
    build:
      context: ./docker-test
    networks:
      - my-network
    extra_hosts:
      - "db-server:172.17.0.1"
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here I'am appending a new host entry **db-server** which gets the value of the **docker0** interface ip.

Is there a solution to dynamically set the **"db-server"** to **my-network gateway ip**?

Comment: This topic is discussed at some length in [From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach); do the solutions there work for you?

Comment: Thanks for your response.
I tried to run this command from th dockerfile to set a host entry manually
`RUN echo "$(ip -4 route list match 0/0 | cut -d' ' -f3)  db-server" >> /etc/hosts`
It didn't work because docker creates a new /etc/hosts file when the container is already up.